# Better way to do this simple IF ELSE?

Tags: php, if-statement, var

Is there a better/simpler/more appropriate way to do this simple PHP? I want to echo something unless the variable is equal to 123.

```
   <?php 
        if ($abc=="123") echo ""; // do nothing
        else echo "something"; 
    ?>
```

Comment: `if ($abc != "123") echo "something";` This is what I think you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo ($abc=="123") ? "" : "something";
```

[**Ternary Operator**](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

and for `I want to echo something unless the variable is equal to 123.` use `!=` logical operator.

```
if ($abc != "123") echo "something";
```

**Comment Response**

You are checking if $abc value is `123` or `456`

now what happen if `$abc` value is `456` conditions for `if` work as below.

```
if($abc != '123' || $abc != '456') // if will be  (true || false) which is false
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Any how might I add another variable to exclude? I tried this but it does not work: '<?php if (($abc != "123") || ($abc !="456")) echo "something"; ?>'

Comment: @codeview you can add `&&` or `||` logical operator based on your need...where `&&` represent `AND` and `||` represent `OR`

Comment: @codeview make sure your `$abc` value are not equal to `123` and `456`

Comment: Do I need the double brackets `(($) || ($))`? `&&` works but `||` shows "something" no matter the variable.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't follow the comment response. BUT...it works with `&&` as I need it to/as I understand it. So thank you, your answer chosen. And I do also need to use double brackets or else I get an error: `<?php if (($abc != "123") && ($abc != "456")) echo "something"; ?>`

Comment: @codeview let me know what you want to do...because if value of `$abc` is not either `123` or `456` you will see `something` as message...

Comment: `(true || false) which is false`? What logical world do you live in? `true || false` is **true**

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg well i am in correct world why don't you think it from OP problem prospect....logic is correct in aspects of OP problem.....

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand you right, but `if($abc != '123' || $abc != '456')` will always evaluate to `true`. As I understand you, you're saying that it will always evaluate to `false`. See Alexander Yancharuk's answer below for the real way to do "multiple variable exclusion"

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do:

`if ($abc != "123") echo "something";`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible way:

```
'123' == $abc or print 'something';
```

Note in that approach you can use `print` only. Cause `echo '...'` [can't be calculated as bool](http://codepad.org/lAjb2GGs), unlike [print](http://codepad.org/h5pncs1x).

**Update**

Multiple variable exclusion example:

```
if ('123' != $abc and '456' != $abc) print 'something';

// this code will do the same stuff
'123' == $abc or '465' == $abc or print 'something';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you lost me with the bool stuff :( So is "print" better to use? And what about multiple variable exclusion? Just like this? `<?php if (($abc != "123") && ($abc != "456")) print "something"; ?>`

Comment: @codeview `print` is not better. It's just have additional functionality which can be useful in some cases.